# Images not displaying on hosting in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I hosted my website on IIS a few days back and it worked perfectly. I then hosted it on another machine and it stopped displaying the images. I checked online and enabled the static content option in turn windows features on/off; it is still not working. Any inputs?

Comment: Are you able to load images by entering the image URL into your browser?

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to check static content checkbox. This [link](http://gurustop.net/blog/2009/10/12/funny-problem-windows-7-iis-7-5-images-css-not-showing/) has the brief description with images.